# Generate only weekend days in Excel

Tags: excel, office365

I am trying in Excel to show only weekend days, but the auto function is only able to show the weekdays.
I would like to obtain in the end a list of only Sat and Sun for a certain period.

Trying to use the WORKDAYS.INTL and WORKDAYS using the start date and a filtering on Sun/Sat, but in Excel 365 that is not working like expected.

Can somebody suggest something?

[image: Not working for me]

Thanks in advance.

[image: Office 365]

Answer (score 0):

With Office 365 Dynamic Array Formula:

```
=FILTER(SEQUENCE(B2-B1+1,,B1),WEEKDAY(SEQUENCE(B2-B1+1,,B1),2)>5)
```

[image]

---

If one does not have the Dynamic Array formula then one can put this in the first cell:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,$B$1):INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,$B$2))/(WEEKDAY(ROW(INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,$B$1):INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,$B$2)),2)>5),ROW($ZZ1)),"")
```

And copy down.

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott, I am getting back an error with your formula. Is SEQUENCE a recognize command from EXCEL?

Comment: do you use `;` instead of `,` for the delimiter?

Comment: And you tagged it Office 365 which introduced the dynamic array formula.  Do you have a 365 subscription or are you using 2016 or 2019 excel?

Comment: 365 ProPlus. I have tried to change all the , into ; but still same.

Comment: Then I do not know, as you can see it works for me.  Try this: `=Sequence(10)` and tell me what you get.

Comment: I can try tomorrow on another PC and different version of excel 2016

Comment: It will not work on anything that is not O365 subscription and is up to date on the releases.

Comment: For this I was asking if the sequence is a recognize excel shortcut..thanks anyway for the help!

Comment: It is a recognized formula if the version is correct.  See my edit for one that works with older versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function weekends(d1 As Date, d2 As Date)
    Dim c As Collection, i As Date, s As String
    Set c = New Collection
    For i = d1 To d2
        s = Format(i, "dddd")
        If s = "Saturday" Or s = "Sunday" Then
            c.Add i, CStr(i)
        End If
    Next i
    
    ReDim temp(1 To c.Count, 1 To 1)
    
    For j = 1 To c.Count
        temp(j, 1) = c.Item(j)
    Next j
    weekends = temp
End Function
```

[image]

In Excel 365 it should spill-down by itself.

**EDIT#1:**

If you have an older version of Excel *(in my case Excel 2007/Win7)* there is not automatic spill-down.  Just select a block of cells in the column and **array-enter** the formula.

Comment: See the comment under my answer, the version the OP has does not include the dynamic array formula.  It will not auto spill, in their version.